# Is exposing column names as json object properties a security risk?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Passing json encoded mysql data sets using fech assoc to javascript can expose table column names if I dont alias every column name. So the question is, is exposing column names as json object properties a security risk?

I am using PDO prepared statements all the way.

Comment: *Hm...* I tend to pull towards "yes", it could be a factor. The less they know, the better it is. You could use aliases. Wait for other answers.

Comment: SO has no problem with exposing column names (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). If you have secured inputs and webhosting, I think there is no need to highly mask your column names.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Or that's what they *want* you to think, bwa hah hah hah...

Comment: Everything is possible :).

Answer (score 5):

Exposing column identifiers by itself shouldn't be a high security risk. The security problem is if you permit SQL injection attacks, even in only one case in your app, someone could use the knowledge about column names to speed up discovery of how to write illicit queries.

But they could find out columns anyway, because if they *can* run arbitrary SQL via SQL injection, they could query your INFORMATION_SCHEMA and find out anything they need.

If you're confident that your query execution is done safely, then you should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's a security concern more than a security risk.  In and of itself, it does nothing bad.  But if can help an attacker if there is a real security risk, such as an injection attack.